# Puppet class inheritance confusion

Tags: puppet

I've read the documentation on scope, but I'm still having trouble working this out. I've got two environments that are very similar - so I've got:

**modules/django-env/manifests/init.pp**

```
class django-env {
    package { "python26":
        ensure => installed
    }
    # etc ...
}
import "er.pp"
```

**modules/django-env/manifests/er.pp**

```
$venvname = "er"
$venvpath = "/home/django/virtualenvs"

class er {
    file { "$venvpath/$venvname" :
        ensure => directory
    }
    # etc ...
}
class er-dev {
    include er
}
class er-bce-dev {
    $venvname = "er-bce"
    include er
}
```

**manifests/modules.pp**

```
import "django-env"
```

**manifests/nodes.pp**

```
node default {
    # etc ...
}
node 'centos-dev' imports default {
    include django-env
    include er-bce-dev
    include er-dev
}
```

The result here is that the "inheritance" works - but only the first "er-" item under the 'centos-dev' node is acted upon, I either get er-bce-dev or er-dev, but not both. There must be some basic thing I'm misunderstanding here.

Is it the difference between *import* and *include* ? (not sure I understand that)

Comment: IIRC the FAQ of puppet contained an item that stated that node inheritance has problems and shouldn't be used. But now the FAQ has moved and lost this piece of information along the way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Puppet does not support this kind of configuration, but the restriction can be easily bypassed. The reason is in two basic puppet "rules":

1. A class can be included only once (subsequent include -statements will do nothing)
2. The order of execution is not strictly defined and can even be random

`er-dev` and `er-bce-dev` both include the class `er`. But the class cannot be included two times, so `er` class is executed only with the default `$venvname = "er"`, or with overridden `$venvname = "er-dev"`, but not both.

The solution: Change `er` class to a definition (see "Definitions" from Puppet Language Tutorial (http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/language_tutorial.html)):

**modules/django-env/manifests/er.pp**

```
# Create new er resource definition
define django-env::er($vpath="/home/django/virtualenvs", $vname="er") {
    file { "$vpath/$vname" :
        ensure => directory
    }
    # etc ...
}
```

We do not need the `$venvname` and `$venvpath` variables, they are specified as default values in the definition. The name `django-env::er` adds the definition into `django-env` namespace and allows automatic import (see below).

### Import and Include

The difference between `import` and `include` statemens is:

- `import` works with files, and does not execute classes
- `include` executes classes
- files must be imported before the classes can be included

Note: there is a very strong exception to the last rule: [Puppet module lookup](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/modules.html#module-lookup). `include` statement does automatic imports in many situations. Here are some of them:

- `include foo` tries to import the file `module_dir/foo/manifests/init.pp`
- `include foo::bar` imports `module_dir/foo/manifests/bar.pp`

With these automatic imports and the resource definition, you can define multiple virtual environments very easily. Change `node 'centos-dev'`:

```
node 'centos-dev' imports default {
    include django-env
    # The er resource with default values:
    django-env::er { 'er-bce': }
    # Another er resource with different environment name:
    django-env::er { 'er-bce-dev': vname => 'bce-dev'}
}
```

And you can remove basically all `import` statements considering `django-env` module.

Happy Puppeting!

Comment: Shouldn't there be `inherits` instead of `imports default`? `inherits` is also deprecated, but at least it's valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet syntax evolved, since Puppet 3.7 you'll get a lot of deprecation warnings. Keywords `import` and `inherits` are deprecated. Instead of using layout like:

```
 /etc/puppet
   /manifests
      /nodes
      site.pp
   /modules
   puppet.conf
```

You should use:

```
 /etc/puppet
   /environments
     /production
       /manifests
          01_base_node.pp
       /modules
       environment.conf
   puppet.conf
```

Instead of using traditional `site.pp` config:

```
import 'nodes/*.pp'

node default {
   classs{'ntp': }
}
```

you should use standard `class` (but you can't call it `class default` as it is a [reserved word](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_reserved.html)), a file `manifets/01_common.pp`:

```
class common {
  classs{'ntp': }
}
```

Files are loaded in an alphabetical order, so you should ensure that "base classes" will be loaded first (numbering might be a good idea).

Then instead of defining a node like:

```
node /^web\d+/ inherits default {
}
```

use rather (resolves classical multiple inheritance problem, so called [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem)), e.g. defined in `manifests/web.pp`

```
node /^web\d+/ {
  include common
  # include something_else   
}
```