# What to use instead of import keyword?

Tags: puppet

I'm using the following sample manifest from [camptocamp/puppet-nagios](https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-nagios):

```
node 'central_monitoring_server' {
  import "nagios"

  $nagiosadmin_password = "XXXX"

  ...

  include apache::base

  include nagios::base
  include nagios::nsca::daemon
  include nagios::webinterface
}
```

However I've the warning:

> Warning: The use of 'import' is deprecated at nagios.pp. See http://links.puppetlabs.com/puppet-import-deprecation

I've followed the link which says:

> New users should avoid the `import` keyword, and existing users should
>   stop using it. Instead, do the following:
>
> - To keep your node definitions in separate files, specify a directory as your main manifest.
> - To load classes and defined types, use modules.
>
> Together, these two features replace import completely.

However this is not clear what actually I should do.

Can I just use the `include` keyword instead of `import` as:

```
include nagios
```

Is that all? Is that should work in the same way?

I'm using puppet v3.7.4.

Comment: Also see: http://serverfault.com/a/223026/13325

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `import` keyword was actually designed to import manifests, not classes, as explained [here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_import.html).

Now that Puppet has evolved and introduced autoloaded modules and a saner directory structure, this functionality is no longer needed, and you should use `include` instead.